# Aligning radio tag to the image next to it

Tags: css, image, html-table

I want to align my radio tags to the image next to it.

The image is width="260" height="88" and the tag are contained in a table

I tried this but it did not have an affect:

```
form input[type="radio"]{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;

}
```

This is the table:

```
<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>

        <td height="90">    
            <input type="radio" value="">
            <img src="/images.gif" width="260" height="88" />
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: middle` to the image as well. Moreover, since you don't have the `<form>` tag wrapping the radio button, you only need `input[type="radio"]` to apply styles to the radio button using CSS.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

#image {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>

        <td height="90">    
            <input type="radio" value="">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" id="image" width="260" height="88" />
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```